# AWS ECS Service: Load balancer using same subnets and security groups as the service. No option to specify them

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

While creating a Service, I want to use a load balancer, So while creating new Load balancer through service form, I see that it uses the same Network settings mentioned for a service.

I want the service to be in a private subnet.

And Load balancer has to be in a public subnet.

The below image gives more idea of what i am talking

[image]

Currently I have to go to my service and modify the subnets and also security group.

Comment: Did you create an **Application Load Balancer** or a **Network Load Balancer**?

Comment: I create Application Load Balacer (ALB)